# How to turn autocomplete off in an Ajax form in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created an Ajax form in razor. But I need to turn off auto-completion in entire form. In a normal form, I could pass html attribute `autocomplete = "off"` but I can't find a best overload that accepts only `AjaxOptions` and `htmlAttributes` (of any type)

Well [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does not describe all of 17 overloads of `Ajax.BeginForm()`. It has only 11 definitions there.

Well my function call looks like

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() { ... }))
{
    ...
}
```

I am listing some overloads those contains `htmlAttribute` of any type in their definition.

```
Ajax.BeginForm(string actionName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes)

Ajax.BeginForm(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes)

Ajax.BeginForm(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, IDictionary<string,object> htmlAttributes)

Ajax.BeginForm(string actionName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, IDictionary<string,object> htmlAttributes)

AjaxBeginForm(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes)
```

Please tell me which one is that I can make use of without any other functional effect. Or any other solution to add `autocomplete="off"` in `form` tag..?

Comment: can't you pass in an empty string for the action name, and then just use a null for the route values?  you can pull the route values out of the ViewContext if you want to pass them in that way

Comment: @Slicksim Actually I m new to MVC. Let me try if it works

Comment: @Slicksim yeah ! It works :-) Thank u. Please write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, 
        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result" }, 
        new {autocomplete ="off"})
       )
```

Comment: I am passing `URL` in ajax options. Can I remove that from there..?

Comment: yes instead specify the action and controller in my case it was `Index` and `Home`

Comment: It is appending `Length=10` in query string. This is not actually a problem. But why is it for and how can I remove that.?

Comment: Its because you are not passing the right values to constructor. check the constructor and the values you are passing to it.

Comment: No @Jatin that's not. I am passing correct action and controller name. Double checked it. And If I would hv passed wrong action and controller name. This should not work. But ajax call is being made and binding to correct method in controller.

Comment: I found the root of the this `Length` problem. Actually u have missed a `object routeValues` parameter after `controller`. It should be like `("Index", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { ... }, object attributes)`. I have edited ur answer.

Comment: ya the same I was telling about the parameters in constructor and not about the name of controller and view.

Answer (score 1):

can't you pass in an empty string for the action name, and then just use a null for the route values?

you can pull the route values out of the ViewContext if you want to pass them in that way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass model to view with Email and Password properties pre-filled with white spaces.

   new UserEditModel { Email = " ", Password = " "};
2. Reset corresponding inputs in javascript in this way:

   function resetInputs() {

   ```
   $('input[name="Password"]').val('');
   $('input[name="Email"]').focus(function() {
       $(this).val('');
   });
   ```

   }

**Note:** the trick is to clear the password input only and place event handler (on focus) on email input so it is cleared only if user starts typing his email. If you clear both inputs at once it won't work.